# "Tried to convert 'dim' to a tensor and failed" when using expand_dims

Tags: python, tensorflow

I expect the following code to produce the corresponding tensor

```
>>> A = tf.range(3)
>>> B = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(A), [4,1])
>>> print(tf.Session().run(B))

[[0,1,2],
 [0,1,2],
 [0,1,2],
 [0,1,2]]
```

However this results in a `ValueError`. An easy way to reproduce the problem is below

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> x = tf.constant([0,1,2])
>>> y = tf.expand_dims(x)

ValueError: Tried to convert 'dim' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

What is the proper way to use `expand_dims` and avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to specify a value for the `axis` argument of `expand_dims`. The default value is `None` which seems to lead to the error you are getting. This is a little strange because default arguments should normally result in some kind of reasonable default behavior... maybe this is a bug.

Your code should work with `y = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=0)`. This will result in  a shape of `[1, 3]` in your example, allowing you to tile afterwards. Another option would be `y = x[tf.newaxis, :]` which also adds an axis.

Comment: I had my suspicions that this could be a bug. I may open it as an issue on the TF repo. Perhaps `expand_dims` is on its way to being deprecated, as `newaxis` is a more "numpy" way of doing things. Thank you for your answer!